# How to find the conditional distribution?

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution

> Let $ Y \sim Gamma(\alpha, \lambda) $ and $X|Y= y\sim \text{POI}(y)$. Find the conditional distribution $Y|X=x$

How to do that? I  am confused because  the Gamma distribution is a continous distribution and Poisson distribution is a  discrete distribution.  Can it be solved?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

The knowledge of the distributions of $Y$ and $X|Y=y$ gives the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ from which the conditional distribution of $Y|X=x$ can be easily computed.

Indeed the density of $(X,Y)$ w.r.t the product measure $N\otimes \lambda$ where $N$ is the counting measure on $\mathbb N$ is $$f_{X,Y}(k,y) \propto y^{\alpha+k-1}e^{-(\beta+1)y}$$
(removing all the factors that do not depend on $y$)

so $Y|X=k \sim Gamma(\alpha+k, \beta+1) $

Comment: I have got the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$, then what must i do next? To obtain $Y|X$, can I do on this way : $f(X,Y)/f(X)$?

Comment: @Boo230196 yes you can

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll try :)